# How can I backup app data on a user that is not an owner?

Tags: backup, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

I have tried both Samsung Smart Switch and backing up via the Samsung account option in the settings, both of which require my user to be an owner/administrator. The problem is that both of these methods work just fine for transferring app data on my owner user, but none of the data on my other user seems to backup properly.

After extensive research, it appears that I have fallen into a catch 22; I can only backup data on an owner user, but to change a non-owner user to an owner I need to reset my tablet, deleting all tablet data.

Does anyone know of a way I could either change a non-owner user to an owner without data loss, or backup app data on a non-owner user?